# ColdFusion ORM paging with cfquery

Tags: orm, coldfusion

Is it possible to limit the results (for paging) given by a `<cfquery dbtype="hql">` like Raymond Camden demonstrated [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/8/14/Simple-ColdFusion-9-ORM-Paging-Demo) with `EntityLoad`?

```
<cfset items = entityLoad("person", {},url.sort & " " & url.sortdir, {maxresults=pageSize,offset=url.start-1})>
```

In my case the objects could not be requestet with a simple `entityload()` because there are a few things I need to check:

```
<CFQUERY name="qEvents" dbtype="hql">
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN e.event_cat_id AS cat
LEFT JOIN cat.lang_id AS lang
WHERE lang.lang_id = <CFQUERYPARAM value="#session.lang_id()#" />
AND e.active = 1
AND (
        (
            DATE(e.date_begin) >= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
            AND
            DATE(e.date_begin) <= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
        ) 
        OR
        (
            DATE(e.date_end) >= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
            AND
            DATE(e.date_end) <= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
        )
        OR
        (
            DATE(e.date_begin) >= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
            AND
            DATE(e.date_end) <= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
        ) 
        OR
        (
            DATE(e.date_begin) <= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
            AND
            DATE(e.date_end) >= <CFQUERYPARAM value="#somedate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" />
        )
    )
GROUP BY e.event_id
ORDER BY e.date_begin
</CFQUERY>
```

I know there is a `maxrow`-attribute for `<cfquery>` but that's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ormoptions attribute

```
<cfquery name="" dbtype="hql" ormoptions="#{maxresults=pageSize,offset=url.start-1}#"
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. Thank you!